# IOS9 WKWebView Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: ajax, wkwebview

I load local html file on IOS `WKWebview` using `loadFileURL: allowingReadAccessToURL`..
But when I send ajax request, it fails.

The error is:

> Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Can I set some properties to fix this error, like in Android,we can use `setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs`?

Comment: What exactly is ur ajax request?

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried setting it like this?

```
let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
config.setValue(true, forKey: "allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs")
```

Comment: I was getting the null error from image urls referenced in CSS. This fixed it.

Comment: I still can't get JavaScript files to load due to CORS errors even with this setting turned on.

Comment: Found a solution to "this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs", see my comment on https://stackoverflow.com/a/46127440/2715716.

Answer (score 2):

When HTML is loaded locally (file URL) with WkWebView below configuration setting to WkWebView worked for me

```
WKWebViewConfiguration *theConfiguration = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
WKUserContentController *userContentController = [[WKUserContentController alloc] init];

[theConfiguration.preferences setValue:@"TRUE" forKey:@"allowFileAccessFromFileURLs"];
[theConfiguration setValue:@"TRUE" forKey:@"allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs"];
```

When you set above setting, origin will be passed as "file://" instead of null

Comment: This makes the app crash for me with the error "this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs".

Comment: Found a solution to "this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs", see my comment on https://stackoverflow.com/a/46127440/2715716.

Answer (score 0):

Try using loadRequest instead of loadFileURL. It worked for me :

```
NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"pageName" ofType:@"html"];
NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];
[self.webView loadRequest:request];
```

After that, my query worked fine while I had a 'Cannot make any requests from null' error before.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to reading from localhtml file, you have to set allowReadAccess

```
let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
let documentsURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentsPath, isDirectory: true)
let finalURL = URL(string: htmlurl)
webview.loadFileURL(finalURL!, allowingReadAccessTo: documentsURL)
```

Answer (score 0):

On Chrome, CORS requests won't work from localhost dispite proper CORS headers, just saying.. keep banging my head on that one