# WKWebView xmlhttprequest with file url

Tags: javascript, ios, ajax, wkwebview

I am migrating from UIWebView to WKWebView with my local HTMLs in the app documents folder.
I can load the index page with all css and js files, but every ajax call (xmlhttprequest) fails because of allowed-access-origin.

I don´t want to use a webserver in my application, because I think it would be oversized. How can I make it possible? The app is a simple HTML5 application for an in house app. The device can´t get online or anything so security could be disabled completly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This solved my problem:

```
let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
config.userContentController = contentController
config.preferences.setValue(true, forKey: "allowFileAccessFromFileURLs")
webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: config)
webView.uiDelegate = self
webView.navigationDelegate = self
view = webView
```

Comment: Wow thank you! After all this time I can finally migrate from UIWebView to WKWebView. Your solution is working fine for me.

Comment: Note that this works when creating the configuration explicitly and passing into the constructor, but when creating the WKWebView with the default constructor and then accessing .configuration.preferences on it, you might get "this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs". This happens when wrapping the WKWebView in a SwiftUI component with makeUIView (return `WKWebView()` using default constructor) and updateUIView (access `uiView.configuration.preferences` later).

Comment: Has anyone developed 'allowFileAccessFromFileURls' by changing the option?

Answer (score 3):

For those who came though SO to find this topic:

This isn't official to turn off the security in WKWebView, but we could use the private API to allow this just like this guy did for the Cordova project: [cordova-plugin-wkwebviewxhrfix](https://github.com/TheMattRay/cordova-plugin-wkwebviewxhrfix)

The clue is to create the configuration for the WebView and set the allowFileAccessFromFileURLs property.

```
WKWebViewConfiguration* configuration = originalImpSend(_self, selector, settings);

// allow access to file api
@try {
    [configuration.preferences setValue:@TRUE forKey:@"allowFileAccessFromFileURLs"];
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {}

@try {
    [configuration setValue:@TRUE forKey:@"allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs"];
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {}

return configuration;
```

But as I mentioned this is the **private API** and it could be a reason to *reject your application* in Apple's App Review. If you want to publish your app in App Store, please consider to run some lightweight HTTP server instead of violate overall security of the web view. Example: [GCDWebServer](https://github.com/swisspol/GCDWebServer).

Answer (score 2):

So the accepted was not working for me when I first tried it (I was doing it wrong at the time) and the bug about (https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=154916) it strongly recommends against doing it.  My solution was to implement a custom url scheme and use that to load all files.  Looks like this.

First creating the WKWebView to which the url scheme is attached (you must create the WKWebView yourself, it can't be created on a storyboard).

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    configuration.setURLSchemeHandler(PrayerAssetHandler(), forURLScheme: "x-file")

    webview = WKWebView(frame: webContentView.bounds, configuration: configuration)
    self.webContentView.addSubview(webview!)
    webview?.autoresizingMask = webContentView.autoresizingMask
    webview!.navigationDelegate = self

    super.viewDidLoad()
}
```

Then implement the handler.

```
import Foundation
import WebKit
import MobileCoreServices

class PrayerAssetHandler: NSObject, WKURLSchemeHandler {

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, start urlSchemeTask: WKURLSchemeTask) {
        let url = urlSchemeTask.request.url!

        let pathArr = url.path.components(separatedBy: ".")
        let forResource: String = pathArr[0]
        let ofType: String? = pathArr.count > 1 ? pathArr[1] : nil

        let bundlePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "data_sub_folder" + forResource, ofType: ofType)

        let fileExtension: CFString = ofType! as CFString
        guard
            let extUTI = UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension,
                                fileExtension, nil)?.takeUnretainedValue()
        else { return }

        guard
            let mimeUTI: NSString = UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass(extUTI,
                                kUTTagClassMIMEType)?.takeRetainedValue()
        else { return }

        let mimeType: String = mimeUTI as String

        do {
            let data: Data = try NSData(contentsOfFile: bundlePath!) as Data

            //Create a NSURLResponse with the correct mimetype.
            let urlResponse = URLResponse(url: url, mimeType: mimeType,
                                          expectedContentLength: data.count, textEncodingName: "utf8")
            urlSchemeTask.didReceive(urlResponse)
            urlSchemeTask.didReceive(data)
            urlSchemeTask.didFinish()
        }  catch _ as NSError {
            return
        }

    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, stop urlSchemeTask: WKURLSchemeTask) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this example! Two things are not obvious here: For loading a page with your custom scheme, you must provide your own navigationDelegate that confirms your requests. Also remember that `NSResponse` has no status code and will make XMLHttpUrlRequests fail (and/or libraries like axios). Use `NSHttpUrlResponse` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Setting value in preferences is not working in Swift 5.
Set in '***WKWebViewConfiguration***' as shown below.

```
// Configuration
let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
webConfiguration.preferences.setValue(true, forKey: "allowFileAccessFromFileURLs")
webConfiguration.setValue(true, forKey: "allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs")

// Web View
let webView = WKWebView(frame: webviewContainer.frame, configuration: webConfiguration)
```

Comment: Is it okay to change the setting of 'allowUniversalAccessFromFileURls'? I think everyone is using it, would there be no problem in the Review?